# $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {x^{2i-1}}{\sqrt{2i}}$ as polylogarithm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function, zeta-functions, polylogarithm

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {x^{2i-1}}{\sqrt{2i}}$$

It is very clear for me that it has to be *polylogarithm function* but as it is partial sum I tried to split the series as

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{2i-1}}{\sqrt{2i}}- \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac {x^{2i-1}}{\sqrt{2i}}$$
then
$\frac {x^{2i}}{\sqrt{2i}}\frac 1x$

as $$Li_n(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k^n}$$

but no luck(:

---

@as per comment @Daarshan P.

[From WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%28x%5Ek%2Fk%5En%29%2C+k+%3D+1+to+infinity)
but how should one proceed if its sum of products $\frac {x^{2i}}{\sqrt{2i}} \& \frac 1x$

Comment: As, it is partial sum it will also include [Lerch Transcendent function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)

Comment: @DarshanP. Okay thanks but now the difficulty is to split the sum of products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac {x^{2i-1}}{\sqrt{2i}}}$$

**Finding the partial sum**
$$\begin{align*}
\color{green}{\sum_{k=1}^m \frac {z^k}{k^n}}
&= \left(\sum_{k\ge1} - \sum_{k\ge m+1}\right)\frac {x^k}{k^n}
\\&=Li_n(x) - \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty\frac {x^k}{k^n}
\\&=Li_n(x) - \sum_{j \ge0}\frac {x^{m+1+j}}{(m+1+j)^n}
\\&=\color{green}{Li_n(x) - x^{m+1}\phi(x, n, m+1)}
\end{align*}$$

Consider,
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^xa_kb_k  \equiv S_xb_x - \sum_{k=1}^{x - 1}S_x(b_{k+1}-b_k)} \text{ Where } \color{green}{S_u = \sum_{k=1}^ua_k}$$

*The blue identity is more of intuitional if we split the consecutive terms of **b***

here, $a_k = \frac {x^{2k}}{\sqrt{2k}} \text{ & } b_k = \frac 1x$

as $\frac 1x $ is independent of $k \implies b_{k+1} -b_k = 0 \text{ or simply } b_\delta = \frac 1x \text{ where } \delta \text{ is anything}$

hence,

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^xa_kb_k  \equiv S_xb_x \text{ Where } \color{green}{S_u = \sum_{k=1}^u \frac {x^{2k}}{\sqrt{2k}}}
\end{align}$$

Here, we get partial sum
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {x^{2k-1}}{\sqrt{2i}} 
&=S_nb_n\\
&=\frac 1x \times \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac {x^{2k}}{\sqrt{2k}}\\
&=\frac 1x \frac 1{\sqrt2}\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac {(x^2)^k}{k^\frac12}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 1{\sqrt 2 x} \left(Li_{\frac 12}(x^2) - x^{2n + 2}\phi(x^2, \frac 12, n + 1)\right)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The blue identity turned solution orange, thanks!!